# How can I achieve OnScroll event for TStringGrid without using TScrollBar?

Tags: delphi

I need to do some action as I'm nearing the bottom of the grid while scrolling.Only the OnMouseWheelDown seems to be working.
Can't find any events in cases of:
1)draging the scrollbar
2)using the down arrow buttons.

Comment: When a grid is scrolled along horizontal or vertical axis, coordinates of top-left cell will change and that should emit an [OnTopLeftChanged](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomDrawGrid.OnTopLeftChanged) event.

Comment: If you want to handle the actual scroll events, you will have to subclass the grid's `WindowProc` to catch `WM_(H|V)SCROLL` messages directly. As for arrow keys, they don't generate key messages by default unless you ask for them by catching `WM_GETDLGCODE` to return `DLGC_WANTARROWS`